# Exe locked after exit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, windows-7, 64-bit

Switched development to 64bit windows and I'm having an issue. After I quit the executable it is still locked for at least 5min and sometimes until I reboot. So I can't do a new build, which makes development a little slow and frustrating.

Filelock reports it to be locked by "system" (helpful) and can't unlock it, even running as admin. It doesn't appear to be runni=ng in procexp or taskmanager.

This is a C++ app using Qt, with vs2010 pro on Windows7 pro 64bit - not sure if any of those are the problem, it was fine on 32bit.

Has anyone else seen anything like this?

Comment: Is this a minimal Qt application? If not, does a minimal Qt application have the same problem?

Comment: No it's just my main app and it's been through a lot of changes of Qt version etc. And it happens for all the projects in my build. I might try just recreating all the solution/projects from scratch.

Comment: Disable your virus scanner.  Uninstall it if it is named Avast.

Comment: @HansPassant - never use a virus scanner, I'm a developer not an id10t

Comment: Well, always good to mention these things, developers should know how virus scanners mess up stuff.  You still have an environmental problem that can't be chased down until you provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I frequently have similar problems, which in my case are caused when I'm debugging an application that uses a MIDI device.  If the app crashes or I stop debugging (ie stopping in the debugger, rather than letting the app finish normally) then one driver on my system doesn't release the device.  The process resists all attempts to kill it.  Either I have to disconnect the device temporarily (so the driver gets released) or reboot.  As a workaround I can usually just rename the .exe which means that I can link again, though I end up with lots of zombie processes.

So the first thing to check is whether there are any particular I/O devices you're using in this app, and whether the drivers are up to date.  If you don't think there's any specific drivers you're using then try running `windbg`, attach to the process and type `!analyze -v -hang`.  This may tell you which driver dll it's waiting on.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a stupid idea- But try changing the file ownership to you again, and turn on "Take Ownership" in the file system settings.

It is annoyingly common to own a folder, and not all the files inside it.

Comment: I own it, it's in the output folder in my VS project. It's just that exiting it leaves something behind.